# Change database connection at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sqlite, database-connection

**Given**

I have a model that requires a connection to a dedicated in-memory SQLite database. What I am doing is – creating a connection at a class level like this (here I'm skipping schema definition using connection provided by `ExternalDatabase`):

```
class ExternalDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite', database: ':memory:')
end

class MyModel < ExternalDatabase
end
```

**Problem**

I suspect that the above definition is error-prone when accessing from multiple threads. A good example of it is when running Sidekiq workers that write to the database simultaniously from their threads.

So the question are:

1. Is my suspicios correct about read/write conflicts when accessing database from different threads? Does `sqlite` locks resources on a lower level thus enable safe concurrent acces to reading/writing?
2. How do I change connection to an in-memory SQLite database for a given model at a runtime? `ActiveRecord::Base#establish_connection` doesn't work for me since I'm using in-memory DB.

   I would like to achieve something like this:

   ```
   klass = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base)
   klass.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite', database: ':memory:')  

   create_schema(klass.connection)

   MyClass.connection = klass.connection
   ```

   But Rails lacks direct `#connection=` method on an `ActiveRecord::Base` (though it has undocumented `#connection_id` which still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two conclusions made:

1. for in-memory DB, a thread always gets a uniqe connection, i.e. its own version of DB, will always be "fresh" and will not interfare with similar DBs in other threads.
2. for regular DB one should make sure connection is establish at a runtime not within the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use.

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q6

My quick reading of it indicates that you can get away with multiple treads access the same sqlite database but it is something you should try to avoid doing and comes with some pitfalls.